# reformulation de "pourra lui être unie dans l’exception, la transgression"

Tags: expressions

Pouvez-vous reformuler cette phrase:

> Les sœurs du souverain lui sont liées sous le régime de l’ambiguïté puisque l’une d’entre elles – dans plusieurs royaumes – pourra lui être unie dans l’exception, la transgression.

Comment: Pouvez vous expliquer ce que vous comprenez et ne comprenez pas dans cette phrase ? Cela nous aide à être plus précis, et évite de sortir du cadre de ce forum.

Comment: Je n'ai pas compris cette partie : "pourra lui être unie dans l’exception, la transgression."

Comment: Je vote pour clore. Le contexte est requis pour la compréhension du sujet du texte. Le français est limpide dans l'extrait. La reformulation de phrase n'est pas une question sur la langue française. Merci.

Answer (score 1):

> l’une d’entre elles pourra **lui** être unie **dans** l’exception, la transgression

peut être restructurée comme ceci:

> l'une d'entre elles pourra être unie **à lui**, **et cette union serait considérée comme une** exception, **une** transgression

Comment: Merci infiniment

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Tout dépend du niveau en français de la personne. à mon avis, pour quelqu'un de niveau moyen, la position du "lui", et l'utilisation du "dans" peuvent ne pas être intuitives. Certes le sens n'est pas exactement le même, mais je pense qu'il s'en rapproche avec une construction beaucoup plus explicite... Et je ne vois pas l'alternative à "union" dont tu parles